# Vertical align for div with text and other div with picture (BEM)

Tags: css, html, bem

I'm working on my third project, and I need help.
I need to align text and pic like on added picture.
So this is my HTML:

```css
._colon {
 width: 700px
}


.big-cars-list {
 list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 58px 0 0 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.big-cars-list__item {
 margin: 0 0 14px 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.big-cars-list__item__name {
 font: 700 53px Verdana, sans-serif; 
 margin: 0 0 18px -3px; 
 color: #000; padding: 23px 0 10px;
}

.big-cars-list__item__price {
 font: 700 21px Verdana, sans-serif; 
 margin: 0 0 11px 0; 
 color: #000; 
 padding-top: 1px;
}

.big-cars-list__item__price span {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.big-cars-list__item__link {
 font: 400 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e10025; 
 position: relative;
}

.big-cars-list__item__link:link {
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: #000;
}

.big-cars-list__item__img {
 display: inline-block;
}


.big-cars-list__item__img img {
 max-width: 100%
}

.desc_wrapper{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="_colon">
  <ul class="big-cars-list">
    <li class="big-cars-list__item">
      <div class="desc_wrapper">
        <h2 class="big-cars-list__item__name">Homan 11</h2>
          <h3 class="big-cars-list__item__price"><span>From</span> 200 000 no.</h3>
            <a href="#" class="big-cars-list__item__link">Looking for something?</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="big-cars-list__item__img">
      <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg" alt="Civic 4D" ></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Editable is here: https://jsfiddle.net/qpgtvqba/
Maybe you could help me and told me where is my mistake?[image: what I need]

Comment: I have a question.Why you are using li and ul ? any reason?

Comment: Yes this is one block in list of same items

Comment: you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/qpgtvqba/1/

Comment: Something like this, but without a table :)